Construction of Weil restriction in the derived setting
I am currently reading 19.1,2 in SAG by Lurie about Weil restrictions. In the classical case, Weil restriction is the right adjoint to the pullback functor along some morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$, and in some nice cases, such Weil restriction exists. For our derived case, if we denote $St$ as the infinity category of derived stacks, then consider $X,Z\in St/Y$ for some fixed derived stack $Y$, by 19.1.2.2 in SAG, we have the existence of such 'internal mapping space' $Map_{/Y}(X,Z)$ for representable morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ (see also 6.1 in this paper): 
Then we have the Weil restriction constructed from this: for a morphism of derived stacks $f:X\rightarrow Y$, we have a right adjoint to the pullback $f^{*}$, denoted as $Res_{f}$ or $Res_{X/Y}$

$\textbf{Question:}$ I am really curious about why we need to do the pullback along $Y\rightarrow Map_{/Y}(X,X)$  to get the final right adjoint, the original internal mapping object $Map_{/Y}(X,Z)$ already satisfies the adjoint requirement, and also it is natural with respect to $Z$ (because the final Weil restriction is constructed from it directly under pullback with something unrelevant with $Z$). I can see that when everything $(X,Y,Z)$ are derived schemes, this Weil restriction gives back exactly the same value as the $Map_{/Y}(X,Z)(T)$ as shown in Remark 6.1.4 in this.

I finally figure out my mistakes and I am not sure whether I should delete this question or answer it, because it seems a little strange to answer my own question. Anyway, I shall record it here.
As we see in the definition of $Map_{/Y}(X,T)$, the equivalence $St_{/Y}(Z,Map_{/Y}(X,T))\simeq St_{/Y}(Z\times_{Y} X,T)$ happens in the $\textbf{same}$ category $St_{/Y}$.
So the problem lies in $\textbf{how to construct an adjoint to pullback functor}$ (with domain $St_{/Y}$ and codomain $St_{/X}$) $\textbf{from the internal hom object}$ which exists as an object in $St_{/Y}$.
For $T\rightarrow X\rightarrow Y\leftarrow Z$, we have the equivalence between mapping spaces: $Map_{St_{/X}}(Z\times_{Y} X,T\rightarrow X)\simeq Map_{St_{/Y}}(Z\times_{Y}X,T\rightarrow X\rightarrow Y)\times_{Map_{St_{/Y}}(Z\times_{Y} X,X\rightarrow Y)}\{Z\times_{Y} X\stackrel{projection}{\longrightarrow} X\}\simeq Map_{St_{/Y}}(Z,Map_{/Y}(X,T))\times_{Map_{St_{/Y}}(Z,Map_{/Y}(X,X))}\{p\}$, here $p:Z\rightarrow Map_{/Y}(X,X)$ denotes the morphism corresponding to the projection map $Z\times_{Y} X\rightarrow X$ under the equivalence defining the 'internal mapping object'. So it remains to understand this $p$.
First, by taking $Z=Y$, we have $St_{/Y}(Y,Map_{/Y}(X,X))\cong St_{/Y}(Y\times_{Y}X\cong X,X)$, the projection map in the latter space corresponds to a canonical morphism $*:Y\rightarrow Map_{/Y}(X,X)$, $*$ is actually the $p$ in the case when $Z=Y$.
For the general case of $Z$, if you take a closed look at the projection map, it actually factorizes: $Z\times_{Y} X \rightarrow Y\times_{Y} X\cong X\in St_{/Y}$, because the equivalence between internal hom object and pullback is natural, we can see that $p$ is the composition of $Z\rightarrow Y\in St_{/Y}$ with * morphism.
Thus we have $Map_{St_{/X}}(Z\times_{Y}X,T\rightarrow X)\simeq Map_{St_{/Y}}(Z,Map_{/Y}(X,T)\times_{Map_{/Y}(X,X)}Y)$. Here $Map_{/Y}(X,T)\times_{Map_{/Y}(X,X)}Y)$ is pullback along the $*$ morphism.
(See HTT 5.5.5.12 for the relationship of mapping space in the slice category and the original category).

Might be instructive to look at the "toy case" when everything around is just plain sets and moreover $Y$ is a single point. In this case, $\operatorname{Res}{X/Y}(Z)$ for $g:Z\to X$ is given by $\prod{x\in X}g^{-1}(x)$, which can be identified with the set of sections of $g$, i. e. maps $s:X\to Z$ such that $gs$ is the identity of $X$.

This is the same as $(g^X)^{-1}(\operatorname{id}_X)$, i. e. the pullback along $g^X:Z^X\to X^X$ of $\text{(name of $\operatorname{id}_X$)}:1\to X^X$
